# ios get the coordinate of northeast and southwest in map screen

Tags: iphone, ios, google-maps

I am beginner to iPhone application. I am going to develop the app using google map.
When user drag in map screen and change the content of map screen, I want to get the coordinate of northeast and southwest in current map screen. After user zoom out/zoom in, user can change the content of map screen. In this case, I must get the coordinate of northeast and southwest. I didn't find the method for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do like this ([See that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7993625/in-mkmapview-calculate-distance-between-two-points)) :

```
MKMapRect mapRect = self.mapView.visibleMapRect;

MKMapPoint cornerPointNE = MKMapPointMake(mapRect.origin.x + mapRect.size.width, mapRect.origin.y);
CLLocationCoordinate2D cornerCoordinateNE = MKCoordinateForMapPoint(cornerPointNE);

MKMapPoint cornerPointSW = MKMapPointMake(mapRect.origin.x, mapRect.origin.y + mapRect.size.height);
CLLocationCoordinate2D cornerCoordinateSW = MKCoordinateForMapPoint(cornerPointSW);
```