# How to restrict the google map view from panning beyond provided coordinate bounds?

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps, google-maps-sdk-ios

I'm using Google maps sdk in ios.
I want to restrict the user from viewing other states than the states he is allowed to view. The allowed region to view on the map is given as coordinates (FarRight Latitude and Longitude), (Near Left Latitude and Longitude) and the (Center latitude and Longitude).

------X

---

---X---

---

X------

- X marks the allowed map coordinates on the big map.

When the user pans the map to a coordinate outside this boundary then it has to be panned back to the old location.
But the problem is, In google maps SDK, 
- (void)mapView:(GMSMapView*)mapView didChangeCameraPosition:(GMSCameraPosition*)position
The above method gives the position of the visible map coordinate. From the property "Position" we can get only the target center coordinate not the boundar coordinate. How to solve this issue ?

Thanks.

Comment: Try this answer, since GoogleMapsSdk implement CLLocation and Mapkit  and a lot of stuffs like that. http://stackoverflow.com/a/2082247/1696598