# How to restrict google place auto complete api result to New york only?

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, core-location

I am using **google place auto complete API** to search addresses in my app. I wanted to restrict google place auto complete results to specific city (i.e searching addresses in new york only).

I know this can be done through the **Bound coordinates** but I don't know how to find it (i.e New york specific bound coordinates)

I searched through the documentation for how to restrict results to specific city(i.e New york only) but it's very confusing.

> Note: I am using GMSAutoCompleteController for google auto complete
>   API.

Please let me know how to accomplish it.

```
// Code :

 @IBAction func textfieldDidTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        listingAddressTextfield.resignFirstResponder()
        let controller = GMSAutocompleteViewController()
        let filter = GMSAutocompleteFilter()
        filter.type = .address
        controller.autocompleteFilter = filter
        controller.delegate = self
        present(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }


// Delegate Methods...

extension ViewController: GMSAutocompleteViewControllerDelegate {
    func viewController(_ viewController: GMSAutocompleteViewController, didAutocompleteWith place: GMSPlace) {
        listingAddressTextfield.text = place.name
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    func viewController(_ viewController: GMSAutocompleteViewController, didFailAutocompleteWithError error: Error) {
        print("Error: ", error.localizedDescription)
    }
    func wasCancelled(_ viewController: GMSAutocompleteViewController) {
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two properties of `GMSAutocompleteViewController` available to restrict and bias your location search.

User `GMSCoordinateBounds` which contains `northEast` and `southWest` coordinates. So you need `northEast` and `southWest` coordinate of New York city.

```
controller.autocompleteBounds = Instance of GMSCoordinateBounds
```

Then after you need to set

```
controller.autocompleteBoundsMode = .restrict
```

which will search places within your bounded area.

Comment: Thanks sagar. I have one question about northEast and southWest coordinates, where I can get those? I know new york's latitude is 40.730610, and the longitude is -73.935242

Comment: I'm not very well aware about getting exactly northEast and southEast, But looks this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2081753/getting-the-bounds-of-an-mkmapview. I'm sure it's help you.

Comment: Sure I will look into it. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Happy to Help You. :)